# C# Excel setting min/max for X-axis in line chart

Tags: c#, excel, charts, visual-studio-2015

How do I set the min/max of X-axis (category) for a **line chart** in C# using Visual Studio 2015? The code I have below works for Scatter chart but it does not work for line chart. I searched everywhere but haven't found a good solution. Any hint/solution is appreciated!

```
Excel.Axis Xaxis = Graph.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlCategory, Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary) as Excel.Axis;
Xaxis.TickLabels.Font.Size = 6;
Xaxis.HasMajorGridlines = true;
Xaxis.HasTitle = true;
Xaxis.AxisTitle.Text = "X-axis";
Xaxis.MinimumScaleIsAuto = false;
Xaxis.MinimumScale = 0.00;
Xaxis.MaximumScaleIsAuto = false;
Xaxis.MaximumScale = 1.00;
Xaxis.MajorUnitIsAuto = false;
Xaxis.MajorUnit = 0.10;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set minimum,maximum scale for Category axis?

Axis.MinimumScale, Axis.MaximumScale works only on value axis i.e. y-axis. Your code will throw exception at run-time.